# In React JS we should use jquery library or not for dependency plugins

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-redux

if we are including bootstrap in our admin panel then dependency is jquery. This is right way to include jquery with react js or any other alternative.Like i was using dropify plugin but for this i need jquery because of plugin dependecy. What is best approach in reactjs for jquery dependecy plugins

Answer (score 1):

I think typically it's best not to use jQuery and React together. I ran into some issues with it using Foundation and React. Mostly relating to when jQuery was loaded vs. when a component was rendered. That may have just been my particular situation though.

For Bootstrap specifically, you should consider [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/). It is components styled with Bootstrap CSS, but doesn't rely on either jQuery, or `bootstrap.js`.

If you really need jQuery, I don't think there's any harm in just including a `<script>` for it in your HTML.